# Best way to score range of values in series using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and am sure there's a better way to perform the following score.

Goal: Take a range of values for a column and score it 0-100 with 0 = min for column, 100=max.

I am achieving the goal with the following brute-force approach that I'm sure is far from good.

```
df['range_old'] = (df['col_to_score'].max() - df['col_to_score'].min())
df['range_new'] = 100
df['score'] = (((df['col_to_score']-df['col_to_score'].min())/df['range_old']))*100

df.drop(columns=['range_old', 'range_new'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

The code is hard to read or comprehend later.   **What's a cleaner way to do something like this, or even with more calculations than this, on a cell?**

I sure appreciate the guidance as I try to learn the correct way of doing things in Pandas.  As is, I'm a complete novice.

Comment: I think that is a totally reasonable approach. The only thing is that you should just save your "range" values into variables rather than as columns in your dataframe. Just create variables `range_old` and `range_new`. Then you don't have to delete them from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly more compact way to do it. You can take advantage of lambda functions and broadcasting to get a lot done more compactly in Pandas. First, some dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,5,0], 'B': [10,10,20,50,0], 'C': [20,20,20,50,0]})
```

Next, we can precompute the existing ranges by using the [`apply` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) off of the dataframe and running along the 0 axis:

```py
ranges = df.apply(lambda col: col.max() - col.min(), axis=0)
```

This yields ranges of 5, 50, and 50, respectively. Next, we can use [broadcasting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#flexible-binary-operations) to create a new dataframe of normalized scores according to these ranges.

```py
scores = df / ranges * 100
```

You could chain the last 2 steps together into a single line if you wanted, but I think it reads better broken out this way. The final result you get is:

```
       A      B      C
0   20.0   20.0   40.0
1   20.0   20.0   40.0
2   40.0   40.0   40.0
3  100.0  100.0  100.0
4    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

which I believe is consistent with your intent.

If you really only need to obtain for a single column, you can modify the above line to only calculate for the column in question.

```py
scores_A = df['A'] / ranges['A'] * 100
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - I greatly appreciate you taking the time.  2 questions.   1) How do you score just a single column and not the entire dataframe.   I tried df['col_to_score'] = df.apply(....) but get errors.   2) I notice you import numpy but don't see where it's used.  Why?  Thank you!

Comment: @A36 no sweat. I'll modify the answer with the single-column as well, but basically, you take the line `scores = df / ranges * 100` and simply modify it for the column you want: `this_score = df['this_column'] / ranges['this_column'] * 100`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `sklearn` and its `preprocessing`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scores = df['col_to_score'].values
dummy = scores.reshape(-1,1) #to prevent Expected 2D array error
rescaled_scores = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(dummy) #this will return a 2D array
flattened_list = rescaled_scores.flatten() 
df = df.assign(new_column_name = pd.Series(flattened_list*100)) 
#multiplied with 100 at the end, to rescale betwen 0 and 100
```